# HTML button element in consistency

Tags: html, tomcat, post, button, browser

I have used some **button elements** in my **Spring MVC** application form. While **Chrome** is returning the **value** attribute to the server over **POST** in all environments, IE 10 is returning the button **text** when the environment is **tomcat server**. The interesting thing is that it returning the correct **value** attribute when the environment is **localhost(VMWare vFabric TC server)**. What is this? Does the POST data depend upon the server that we are using?

Comment: are you using any javascript framework on to your form?

Comment: Yes! We are using JQuery.

Comment: The issue may be with jQuery. Check the values before you submit.